# How to call positional arguments explicitly from function call

Tags: python, arguments, positional-argument

I have a function with positional arguments. as the function is more complex (this is only to show you my purpose), i want to explicitly write in the function call the name of the arguments.

```
def my_function(a, b, *other):
    print(a)
    print(b)
    for item in other:
        print(item)
```

I want to avoid writing:

```
my_function(1, 2, 4,5,6)
```

and write it like:

```
my_function(a=1, b=2, other=*[4,5,6])
```

python (3.x) does not allow writing things like my_function(a=1, b=2, 4,5,6) . we get this error because of the mapping *SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument*

is there any way i could mention "other" in the signature ? it seems like all names of arguments must be named or nothing.

thanks if you have any tip.

Comment: If you want the function to be called using the argument names, then why is your function parameter `*other` instead of just `other`?

Comment: because i need to pass many parameters (number is not known in advance) ...

Comment: And then you can call it as `my_function(a=1, b=2, other=[4,5,6])`, putting any number of arguments into `other`. What's the problem with that?

Comment: Read the official documentation to properly understand the convention for defining function parameters. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#special-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, once you use the first keyword argument when calling, all following arguments must be keyword arguments.

You cannot explicitly set the value to be assigned to the `*args` or `**kwargs` parameter, they will be collected according to the callers usage, E.g.,

```py
def f(*args, **kwargs):
  print(f"{args=} {kwargs=}")
```

```
>>> f(args="a", kwargs="b")
args=() kwargs={'args': 'a', 'kwargs': 'b'}
```

An alternative may be to have `other` take a list of values, instead of using `*args`.

Comment: thank you. so i have a confirmation that it is not possible to call positional arguments